# How to prove if a Transformation is Linear or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Okay, so I get the part about obeying scalar addition and multiplication. The question is as follows:

Given $A, B, C, X$ to a $C^{n\times n}$, prove if the following mappings are linear or not.

1. $X \to AX + XB$
2. $X \to AX + BXC$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.Here is [basic MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). People here will help you to clarify any doubt you have regarding a problem and/or a passage that you are reading. But you need to say first what have you tried, and where exactly you got stuck. The question, in its present form, will attract negative votes and people are tend to overlook at questions which doesn't contain any input from OP.

Comment: you have to calculate for addition $f(X+Y)$ and see if it is $f(X)+f(Y)$ and for multiplication by a scalar that $f(zX)$ is the same as $zf(X)$ for any $z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of linear transformation? What did you try? These are straight forward computations using the definition.

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity in your question ,since linear transformation is defined on vector ,the domain should be vector space.

The vector space $C^{n\times n}$ over what field ? $\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F}_n$ where $n$ is prime.

I assume that what you mean is $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

1. Let $f:\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a map defined by $f(X)=AX+XB$.

For all $X,Y\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $c\in \mathbb{C}$

$f(X+cY)=A(X+cY)+(X+cY)B=AX+XB+c(AY+YB)=f(X)+cf(Y)$.

Hence $f$ is a linear transformation.

I think you can solve the second question by you own.

So I leave it to you.